# Debian Stretch(9) ROS2 build from source: Failed <<< tracetools_trace

Tags: ros, ros2, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m aware that Debian is tier 3, and it’s not officially supported. I’m getting the following error when trying building from source Eloquent Release Patch 2 in Debian Stretch(9):

- Operating System: Debian Stretch(9)
- Installation type: From source
- Version or commit hash: ros2-eloquent Patch Release 2
- DDS implementation: Fast-RTPS

error:

```
~/ros2_eloquent$ colcon build --event-handlers console_direct+ --packages-select tracetools_trace
Starting >>> tracetools_trace
Traceback (most recent call last):trace - 0.2s]
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 216, in run_setup
    exec(f.read(), g, l)
  File "<string>", line 35
    f'trace = {package_name}.trace:main',
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):             
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 51, in build
    setup_py_data = get_setup_data(self.context.pkg, env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/python/__init__.py", line 20, in get_setup_data
    return dict(pkg.metadata[key](env))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 130, in getter
    desc.path / 'setup.py', env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 242, in get_setup_information
    setup_py, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 283, in _get_setup_information
    cwd=os.path.abspath(str(setup_py.parent)), check=True, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', "import sys;from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet;from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    'setup.py', script_args=('--dry-run',), stop_after='config');skip_keys = ('cmdclass', 'distclass', 'ext_modules', 'metadata');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith('_') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data['metadata'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in ('license_files', 'provides_extras')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode('utf-8'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
--- stderr: tracetools_trace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 51, in build
    setup_py_data = get_setup_data(self.context.pkg, env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/task/python/__init__.py", line 20, in get_setup_data
    return dict(pkg.metadata[key](env))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 130, in getter
    desc.path / 'setup.py', env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 242, in get_setup_information
    setup_py, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 283, in _get_setup_information
    cwd=os.path.abspath(str(setup_py.parent)), check=True, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 398, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', "import sys;from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet;from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    'setup.py', script_args=('--dry-run',), stop_after='config');skip_keys = ('cmdclass', 'distclass', 'ext_modules', 'metadata');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith('_') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data['metadata'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in ('license_files', 'provides_extras')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode('utf-8'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
---
Failed   <<< tracetools_trace [0.28s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [1.55s]
  1 package failed: tracetools_trace
  1 package had stderr output: tracetools_trace
Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', "import sys;from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet;from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    'setup.py', script_args=('--dry-run',), stop_after='config');skip_keys = ('cmdclass', 'distclass', 'ext_modules', 'metadata');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith('_') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data['metadata'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in ('license_files', 'provides_extras')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode('utf-8'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371283/debian-stretch(9)-ros2-build-from-source:-failed-%3C%3C%3C-tracetools_trace/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2021-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I’m aware that Debian is tier 3, and it’s not officially supported. I’m getting the following error when trying building from source Eloquent Release Patch 2 in Debian Stretch(9)

Note: Eloquent officially only supports Debian Buster (10). See [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#eloquent-elusor-november-2019-november-2020).

That's not related to in which tier Debian is, it just means Eloquent uses dependencies at versions only available in Buster and newer.

> ```
>   File "<string>", line 35
> ```

```
    f'trace = {package_name}.trace:main',
```

this is a Python 3 f-string, which is only really supported starting with Python `3.6`.

Afaict, [Debian Stretch comes with Python 3.5](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3), which is not compatible.

I believe [ros2/ros1_bridge#305](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/issues/305) is a similar issue.

You could perhaps try using a `venv` or other way to get a newer version of Python 3 on your Stretch target.

---

Edit: apparently, for f-strings specifically, there is the `future_fstrings` package ([F String Invalid Syntax in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182209)) which could allow you to work around this.

However, it's possible/likely there are other parts of Eloquent which also assume/have only been tested with `>=3.6`, so that may not be enough to get things to work reliably.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2021-02-08**:
Yeah, there are some discrepancies with the REP 2000 and [this](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Releases/Release-Eloquent-Elusor/) where it says that supports Debian Stretch (9) as a tier 3 platform for Eloquent... Thanks for the tips though!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-08**:
I would suggest to report that and/or submit a PR to fix the docs.